# Which problem occurs with large synchronous motors in the event of high starting current?

Tags: electric-machine, synchronous-motor

So I was performing a test just recently with a synchronous motor at my school, and the teacher said that starting synchronous motors with a high starting current would cause problems to the machine. I have been trying to find answers to this on the internet but I can't seem to find anything with a good explanation why this occurs. Any help would be well appreciated.

Comment: If the motor is not spinning at the synchronous speed it looks more like a short circuit and pulls excessive current. This can be an issue with the supply as it will load it down. For larger motors a ‘soft start’ regime is used to lessen the effect. Some motors maybe thermally limited in that repeated starts may cause overheating.

Answer (score 1):

"High starting current" probably means current that is significantly higher than the motor's normal operating current, at least two or three times the normal running current and likely more that that. That level of current could overheat the motor's stator windings and damage the insulation fairly quickly. High current in the rotor could also cause thermal problems depending on the rotor design.

There may be differences in the starting features designed into a small or medium sized machine compared to a large machine. A synchronous machine in a school laboratory is likely a small machine, less than a half meter diameter. For a large machine, more than a meter diameter, high starting current might also stress the electrical supply network.